# A live autogrow textarea?

Tags: jquery

I'm also trying to understand how to make a live jquery plugin in general, and I thought this would be a good example.

This plugin that I'm trying to develop is a sort of autoGrow for textarea, which works great so far, but it won't work on live content.

http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/cPBgG/10/

I'm guessing it's because of the `each` which isn't live, but I don't know how to go around it. I've been running into this problem on a regular basis and I can't find a solution.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code

```
$.fn.autogrow = function(options) {
this.filter('textarea').each(function() {

    var $this       = $(this),
        minHeight   = $this.height(),
        lineHeight  = $this.css('lineHeight');

    $(this).css('height','hidden');

    var duplicate = $('<div></div>').css({
        position:   'absolute',
        top:        -10000,
        left:       -10000,
        width:      $(this).width(),
        fontSize:   $this.css('fontSize'),
        fontFamily: $this.css('fontFamily'),
        lineHeight: $this.css('lineHeight'),
        resize:     'none'
    }).appendTo(document.body);

    var update = function() {

        var val = this.value.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
            .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
            .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');

        duplicate.html(val);
        $(this).css('height', Math.max(duplicate.height() + 20, minHeight));
    }

    $(this).change(update).keyup(update).keydown(update);

    update.apply(this);

});

return this;

}
```

Comment: Please make this more "self-contained" by including your code within the posting so it remains useful after the jsFiddle link goes dead.

Comment: For jQuery 1.7+, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in place of `.live()`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cPBgG/18/

You should just iterate the jQuery object and not reselect it from the DOM. Also, you weren't calling `autogrow()` for your new text area.

**Edit**

You could always bind to `DOMNodeInserted` something like this (completely untested.):

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) { 
  if(e.target.classname == 'autogrow') { 
    $(e.target).autogrow();
  }
});
```

The point is, you are going to have to call `autogrow()` for your new text area.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to avoid having to recall the function in the click event? ie the $('textarea').autogrow(); I'm working with another developer that uses JSF and his AJAX cannot allow me to do add this. Thanks

Comment: Perfect, seems to be working. Here is the fiddle for later reference: http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/cPBgG/42/

Answer (score 1):

I would do two things. First, apply the plugin to the newly created textareas and two, change the `this.filter('textarea').each(function() {` line to `$(this).each(function() {`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cPBgG/29/)**.

```
$('.liveText').on('click', function() {
    $('<textarea />').appendTo('#copy').autogrow();
});
```

Comment: Is there no way around it? My partner works in Java/JSF, so when he does his AJAX reload, I have no control and it seems his script doesn't allow me to add these sort of things.  Thanks.

Comment: Around having to include it on the click event that generates the new textarea. As said earlier, I have no control when he does his AJAX, therefor I don't the option to add the $.autogrow when he generates the new textarea.  Thanks.

Comment: If an AJAX call is creating the new autogrow areas, couldn't you place the append and plugin calls on the callback of the AJAX call?

Comment: I wish, but the JSF automatically generates the JS scripts on the server on runtime. (Well we haven't found a way, so I was hoping I could find a solution in Jquery and just modify the plugin)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.liveText').live('click',function(){
    $('<textarea />').appendTo('#copy');
    $('textarea').autogrow(); // This line was added
});

(function($) {

    $.fn.autogrow = function(options) {

        this.filter($(this).selector).each(function() {

            var $this       = $(this),
                minHeight   = $this.height(),
                lineHeight  = $this.css('lineHeight');

            $(this).css('height','hidden');

            var duplicate = $('<div></div>').css({
                position:   'absolute',
                top:        -10000,
                left:       -10000,
                width:      $(this).width(),
                fontSize:   $this.css('fontSize'),
                fontFamily: $this.css('fontFamily'),
                lineHeight: $this.css('lineHeight'),
                resize:     'none',
                'word-wrap':'break-word',
                'white-space':'pre-wrap'
            }).appendTo(document.body);

            var update = function() {

                var val = this.value.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
                    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
                    .replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');

                duplicate.html(val);
                $(this).css('height', Math.max(duplicate.height() + 20, minHeight));
            }

            $(this).change(update).keyup(update).keydown(update);

            update.apply(this);

        });

        return this;

    }

})(jQuery);
    $('textarea').autogrow()
```

Comment: `.live()` has been deprecated and replaced with `.on()`.  See [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Yes, true, as Sparky672 mentioned, it is recommended to use on instead of live if you can load jQuery 1.7+

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way to avoid having to recall the function in the click event? ie the $('textarea').autogrow();     I'm working with another developer that uses JSF and his AJAX cannot allow me to do add this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this method, in jQuery.

```
$(name_textarea).css('overflow','hidden');

setInterval(function(){
    $(name_textarea).css('height', $(name_textarea)[0].scrollHeight+2+'px')
},100);
```

Try it, you can play with de number behind scrollHeight to obtain best results.